# Enabling MSAA in XNA 3.0

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, shader, xna-3.0

I am using XNA 3.0 and I want to use anti aliasing for my 3d scene that has multiple 3d objects. I went to the msdn site and implemented MSAA but I still see jagged edges. Is it because I am not rendering anti alias for each object?

This is the cose snippet:

```
     public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        graphics.PreferMultiSampling = true;
        graphics.PreparingDeviceSettings +=
        new EventHandler<PreparingDeviceSettingsEventArgs>(graphics_PreparingDeviceSettings);
     }
     void graphics_PreparingDeviceSettings(object sender, PreparingDeviceSettingsEventArgs e)
     {
        int quality = 0;
        GraphicsAdapter adapter = e.GraphicsDeviceInformation.Adapter;
        SurfaceFormat format = adapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Format;
        // Check for 4xAA
        if (adapter.CheckDeviceMultiSampleType(DeviceType.Hardware, format,
            false, MultiSampleType.FourSamples, out quality))
        {
            // even if a greater quality is returned, we only want quality 0
            e.GraphicsDeviceInformation.PresentationParameters.MultiSampleQuality = 0;
            e.GraphicsDeviceInformation.PresentationParameters.MultiSampleType =
            MultiSampleType.FourSamples;
        }
        // Check for 2xAA
        else if (adapter.CheckDeviceMultiSampleType(DeviceType.Hardware, format,
                 false, MultiSampleType.TwoSamples, out quality))
        {
           // even if a greater quality is returned, we only want quality 0
          e.GraphicsDeviceInformation.PresentationParameters.MultiSampleQuality = 0;
          e.GraphicsDeviceInformation.PresentationParameters.MultiSampleType =
             MultiSampleType.TwoSamples;
       }
       return;
     }
```